# Why is the output of my quick sort algorithm not displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, quicksort

I just want to ask what's wrong with these set of codes. I can't print an output.

```
function Ascending()
{
var array = new Array();
array[0]=parseInt(document.getElementById("1").value);
array[1]=parseInt(document.getElementById("2").value);
array[2]=parseInt(document.getElementById("3").value);
array[3]=parseInt(document.getElementById("4").value);
array[4]=parseInt(document.getElementById("5").value);

var p, r, i, j, swap, pivot;

function quicksort(array[], p, r);
       if r>p then
     j=partition(array[], p, r);
     quicksort(array[], p, j-1);
         quicksort(array[], j+1, r);


    function partition(array[], p, r);
        i=p;
        j=r+1;
        pivot=array[p];
        do { 
             do i=i+1 while (array[i]<pivot);
             do j=j-1 while (array[j]>pivot);
             if (i<j) swap(array[i], array[j]);
           }
    while (i<j)
        swap(array[p], array[j]);
        return j;
}
}

    for (var j = 0; j <array.length; j++)
{
var output =document.getElementById("display");
output.innerHTML+=array[j]+ ' , ';
}
}
```

I want to put this code in an html. So My problem was how to show the output.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

<del>For instance, you can't have element ID's starting with digits (1-9)</del> (doesn't apply to HTML5+modern browsers) and you shouldn't (can't) use array[] (SyntaxError) in the function arguments (just use array). Halkujabra recommended [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) above, which could be a good place to start / visit.

Comment: Having IDs start with digits is valid in HTML5 and has been supported by browsers for a long time.

Comment: You are right, old habits die hard. Thanks for the correction Felix